# Randomly subsampling the rows of a DataFrame in Pandas, with some conditions

Tags: python, pandas

In Python-Pandas, I have a DataFrame with many rows:

```
A = pd.DataFrame( { 'key1': [1 , 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, ....], 
                    'col1': [ .... ],
                    'col2': [ .... ],
                        ....
                    'col_n': [ .... ],
                    'val1': [0 , 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, ....]} )
```

Each key has one or zero val1==1 row, and all the rest val1=0 rows.

I want to create a new DataFrame where I select all the rows where `val1==1`, and a corresponding ***one*** random sample row where `val1==0` for that same key where `val1==1`. Keys for which `val1==0`for all rows are to be ignored.

```
B = A[ A['val1']== 1]
```

works for the first part. I am not sure how to implement the second part.

Example:
Say I have a table:

```
key1 col1 col2 val1
 1   a     b    0
 1   c     d    0
 1   e     f    1
 1   g     h    0
 2   a     b    0
 2   c     d    1
 2   e     f    0
 3   a     b    0
 3   c     d    0
 3   e     f    0
```

I want to get:

```
key1 col1 col2 val1
 1   a     b    0 #randomly subsampled row where val1==0, for key1==1
 1   e     f    1 #row with val1==1 for key1==1
 2   e     f    0 #randomly subsampled row where val1==0, for key1==2
 2   c     d    1 #row with val1==1 for key1==2
                  #no rows for key1==3, because no rows where key1==3 & val1==1
```

Comment: An actual example would help explain this, at the moment it's very confusing.

Comment: thanks, just added one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

text = """key1 col1 col2 val1
1   a     b    0
1   c     d    0
1   e     f    1
1   g     h    0
2   a     b    0
2   c     d    1
2   e     f    0
3   a     b    0
3   c     d    0
3   e     f    0"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(text), delim_whitespace=True)

def sample(df):
    mask = df.val1 == 0
    if np.all(mask):
        return None
    else:
        idx1 = mask.idxmin()
        idx0 = np.random.choice(mask[mask].index)
        return df.loc[[idx0, idx1]]

df.groupby("key1").apply(sample)
```

the output:

```
        key1 col1 col2  val1
key1                        
1    0     1    a    b     0
     2     1    e    f     1
2    4     2    a    b     0
     5     2    c    d     1
```